# Azure Function App - Returning Context Errors

Tags: node.js, jwt, azure-functions

I am facing issues with JWT Authentication on my Azure Function App:

I am using JWT Middleware to verify a token on each request to my function app:

```
module.exports = {
  authenticate: async (context, req) => {
    const token = extractToken(req);

    try {
      // Verify the token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY);

      if (decoded) {
        
        let query = 'XXX';

        const data = await PortalDB.query(query, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }); 

      
         context.auth = data;
         return context;

        }
      
      }
    } catch (error) {

      if (!token) {
        context.res = {
          status: 401,
          body: 'Unauthorized: Token missing',
        };
        return context.done();
      } else {
        context.res = {
          status: 401,
          body: `Unauthorized: Invalid token: ${error}`,
        };
        return context.done();
      }
      
    }
  },
};

function extractToken(req) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    return null;
  }

  return authHeader.substring(7);
}
```

This 'authenticate' function is  called once a request has been sent to the function app:

```
module.exports = async (context, req) => {
    try {
        await connectToMongoDB();
        await jwtAuthMiddleware.authenticate(context, req); // Authenticate jwt 
        switch (req.method) {
            case 'POST' : 
                if (req.body && !req.body._id) {
                    await createContainer(context, req.body);
                } else if (req.body && req.body._id) {
                    await editContainer(context, req.body);
                } else {
                    return context.res = {
                        status: 400,
                        body: {
                            'success': false,
                            'message': 'An error has occurred'
                        }
                    };
                }
                
                break;
            case 'GET' : 
                await getContainers(context, req.query.id);
                break;
            case 'DELETE' : 
                await deleteContainer(context, req.query.id);
                break;
            default :
                return context.res = {
                    status: 405,
                    body: 'Method not allowed for this endpoint.',
                };
                break;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                'success': false,
                'message': 'An error has occurred'
            }
        };    
    }
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that the JWT is correctly returning the respective error codes, however:

1. I am receiving an error in the console: 'Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'. Do not use both in your script.'
2. The CRUD operations are still running, resulting in unauthorized DB Transactions

I could of course check to see that 'auth' exists on the context headers but that could lead to a security vulnerability

Comment: refer to this for JWT in [azurefunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-javascript/ms-identity-docs-code-functions-nodejs/)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented custom authentication for Azure Functions using JSON Web Tokens (JWT) with this reference [MSDOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure-functions-middlewares/jwt?activeTab=code) and Azure Functions with JWT [Authentication](https://charliedigital.com/2020/05/24/azure-functions-with-jwt-authentication/).

```js
try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]);

    context.res = {
      body: decodedToken.scp.split(" ").indexOf("Greeting.Read") > -1
        ? "Hello. You were able to access this because you provided a valid access token.Read  claim."
        : "Missing required scope.",
      status: 200, 
    };
  } catch (error) {
    context.res = {
      body: "Invalid token.",
      status: 403,
    };
  }
```

[image]

[image]

- Another method is adding a user and accessing it.Code reference for build an [Authentication API](https://charliedigital.com/2020/05/24/azure-functions-with-jwt-authentication/) with JWT Token in [Node.js](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-build-authentication-api-with-jwt-token-in-nodejs/)

```js
const  accessToken = jwt.sign(

{  "username":  foundUser.username  },

process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,

{  expiresIn:  '30s'  }

);

const  refreshToken = jwt.sign(

{  "username":  foundUser.username  },

process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,

{  expiresIn:  '1d'  }

);

const  otherUsers = usersDB.users.filter(person  =>  person.username !== foundUser.username);

const  currentUser = { ...foundUser,  refreshToken  };

usersDB.setUsers([...otherUsers,  currentUser]);

await  fsPromises.writeFile(

path.join(__dirname,  '..',  'model',  'users.json'),

JSON.stringify(usersDB.users)

);

res.json({  'success':  `User ${user} is logged in!`  });
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Referred from this [git](https://github.com/gitdagray/user_auth).